# PHP Class and Function return

Tags: php, function, class

I have problem with PHP class and function.

My class file is:

```
<?php
class EF_IP{

public function ip_adresa(){

    // dobivanje IP adrese
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        return $ip;
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            return $ip;
                } else {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    return $ip;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And i call from other PHP file:

```
EF_IP::ip_adresa();
echo $ip;
```

And i get error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method EF_IP::ip_adresa() should not be called statically
```

What i need to do?

Comment: Change `public function` to `public static function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make your function STATIC or instantiate the class first:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function SomeFunction() {}
    public function someOtherFunction() {}
}
```

Then you call either like so:

```
MyClass::SomeFunction()
$class = new MyClass();
$class->someOtherFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function not staticly:

```
$ef_ip = new EF_IP();
$ip = $ef_ip->ip_adresa();
echo $ip;
```

or you make your function static:

```
public static function ip_adresa(){
 // your code
}
```